# Is there any way to disable visited links privacy settings in my firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, privacy, visited

I'm worinkg on my own userscript in tampermonkey for third party website and need to parse all my unvisited links. Is there any way to make visisted links accesible via JS for whole firefox or certain domain?

EDIT: My question is not about "How to test if link has been visited" as MDN saying it's not possible for security reasons. My question is about "How to disable this security checks only fo my own browser".

Comment: @mplungjan I didn't find any related info there. I already have some amount of visited links (in case you're talking about storing such info in cookies). And I don't need any css styling.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n8F9U/

Comment: @mplungjan It says "Not visited" for both links.

Comment: Yes, the answer is still: not possible